# Media Player play each sound file twice

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I want each sound file in my database to play twice before playing the next sound file.

Here is my class.

```
    public void startSlides() {

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Intent intent = getIntent();

                    int setId = intent.getIntExtra("SelectedSetId",0);

                    databaseAccess.open();


                    setId = setId + 1;


                    final List<byte[]> audio = databaseAccess.getAudioA(setId);

                    if (i > audio.size()){
                        i = 0;
                    }else{
                        playAudio(audio.get(i));
                        i++;}


                    List<String> vocab = databaseAccess.getVocabNameA(setId);
                    textView2.setText(vocab.get(k));
                    k++;

                    textView.setText(+j + "/" + vocab.size());
                    j++;

                    databaseAccess.close();

                    if (j == vocab.size() + 1) {
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }, 0, DURATION);

}
```

I have tried to call the play audio method twice, but it is not working (It just plays the same file at the SAME time).

```
    final List<byte[]> audio = databaseAccess.getAudioA(setId);

                    //first time

                    if (i > audio.size()){
                        i = 0;
                    }else{
                        playAudio(audio.get(i));
                        i++;}

                    //second time 

                    if (i > audio.size()){
                        i = 0;
                    }else{
                        playAudio(audio.get(i));
                        i++;}
```

Anyone got any suggestion how should i do it? Thank you

Comment: *how to fix my code?*  **what is broken?**  Is maybe `playAudio` starting a new Thread?  You need to wait for it to finish - wild guess!

Comment: @ScaryWombat, i mean any suggestion how should I do it to play the audio file twice.

Comment: Im sorry, i dont get what you mean.

Comment: Did you bother to read and try to understand my initial comment ?

Comment: Yes, i do, havent figured out how should I do that way.

Answer (score 0):

doing this way might help you:

```
private int mPlaybackCount = 0;

mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    if(mPlaybackCount < 1){
                         mPlaybackCount++;
                         // Play Song again
                    } else {
                         mPlaybackCount = 0;
                         // Play Next Song
                    }


                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi, i have added this into my playAudio method, but it is still not working.